# Find a model by a custom property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model which has a custom property:

```
class User < ActiveRecord
  def my_custom_field
    # ....
  end
end
```

I need to find a user which has a certain `my_custom_field`. I can't do this:

```
User.where(my_custom_field: '123')[0]
```

However, I can do this:

```
User.all.select { |x| x == '123'}[0]
```

but it's not efficient performance-wise. What's a more effective way?

Comment: this is called virtual attribute

Comment: @Anthony, what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're saying is that the `my_custom_field` is not stored in the database. In that case, what you're looking for is [`detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect).

```
users.detect { |user| user.my_custom_field == '123' }
```

Using `detect` will cause the loop to stop iterating as soon as a result is found and return it.

Comment: Getting users require User.all which is the same thing as I did, but I'd like a more efficient solution which doesn't require traversing over all the users on the client.

Comment: If the attribute isn't in the database then there's not much you can do other than iterate over an in-memory collection. Perhaps a more detailed/specific question/scenario would help?